# Chef execute block

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

First off, I'm very new to coding and to Chef so please bear with me if I ask stupid questions.

Is there a way to have my execute block within a recipe only run if the user doesn't match.  It's just a simple one line statement: chown -R aaa:aaa file/path.  So if the owner of file/path is already aaa, don't run this.

If I wasn't clear on the question, I apologize and I'll try to clear it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not_if`, like this:

```
require 'etc'

execute "chown file/path" do
  command "chown -R aaa:aaa file/path"
  not_if { Etc.getpwuid(File.stat("file/path").uid).name == "aaa" }
end
```

If you want to also check the group, just add that to the condition.

Note that your approach is not really idempotent though, since the directory could be owned by `aaa` but include files by others. It seems better to just always run the `chown`, with no condition, so that it forces all the contents to `aaa:aaa`. If the files are already `aaa:aaa`, then nothing happens.

Comment: Not exactly nothing happens when calling chown/chmod with no change on a file, the change time of the file is updated, which could have side effects on backups systems letting them think the file has in fact changed..

Answer (score 4):

So the other answer is technically correct, but the real way to do this is to use a `file` resource:

```
file 'file/path' do
  owner 'aaa'
  group 'aaa'
end
```

That is already idempotent (a fancy word for "don't change things that are already fine") internally.

Comment: I'd add that if it's a directory, rather than a file, then you can use the directory resource.  the `-R` could be a problem, however.  I'm not aware of a way to have the directory resource apply the chown recursively.

Comment: I agree `file` (or `directory`) would be better usually, but the asker wants to recursively change everything (`chmod -R`). How do you do that with `file` or `directory`?

Comment: Sth to watch out for with the `directory` resource: Even if you do use the `recursive` attribute (that indicates you want to create the full directory structure, in case it does not yet exist) this does not mean the `owner`, `group` and `mode` attributes will apply on all the directory structure. In fact: ```For the owner, group, and mode properties, the value of this attribute applies only to the leaf directory.```